# At which rank should I reasonably stop selecting interview candidates?

Tags: ranking, optimal-stopping, optimal

It seems that my problem could be classified as an "optimal stopping" problem, but I am unable to make much of this information. It is an important problem for my organisation (an NGO), in order to optimise fairness vs cost.

**Context**

We have every year an open recruitment for a number of roles, and we get hundreds of candidate for each position, with **only one slot available** per position. Because we're a small team, we can not possibly interview each applicant, so we first create a ranking. The ranking is done as follows:

- Applicants apply through a form which has a number of questions.
- Each question is designed to match a specific criterion that we value for the role and is given a weight (0.5, 1, 2)
- When reviewing applicants, we score their response to each question using a 0-1-2 scale.
- The final score of each applicant is consequently the sum of each individual question score, weighted.

Now that we have a ranking we need to decide how many of the top applicants we interview, and this is where we struggle to find a formalized and fair way to do it.

**The problem**

Consider this list of scores:

```
26, 22, 18.5, 18, 16.5, 16, 15, 12, 7, 8
```

Is there a way to determine a lead group of applicants that we should consider interviewing, knowing that more than 5 participants (per role) puts a lot of strain on our limited resources?

Some observations on the set:

- The variation in score is minimal from one rank to the next even though it is huge from top to bottom.
- The biggest variations from one score to the next are between ranks `1` and `2` (+4), and rank `8` and `9` (+5)

So interviewing everybody would not make sense, but at which point should we stop?

- After the first candidate? It would not make sense for a recruitment process.
- After the 8th candidate? it would mean going too far down the list (there are 10 points of difference between rank 2 and rank 8).
- After the 2nd quintile? Here it could work, but on a full set of 100 candidates, even the first quintile is 20 candidates, which is too many to interview.

Some details on the cost per interview, as it seems important to define it for an optimal stopping problem:

- Each interview is 4h of effective work
- The time to select applicants is also relevant, as selecting between 10 applicants take about 1.5 more time than selecting between 5 applicants (which takes 4h).
- Anything deviating too much from the cost of interviewing 5 applicants (5 * 4 + 4 = 24h) puts a strain on our resources

**What we currently do**

Right now our baseline is that we will interview the top five among the ranked candidates. We add candidates to this group if:

- there are multiple candidates ranked 5 because they have the same score
- there are female applicants within 0,5 points of the 5th candidate (we are in the technology sector so that is our way to counterbalance the systemic difficulties that female applicants face). If we do select female applicants that way, we also interview any male applicants between the 5th ranked applicant and the additional female applicant.

With this system we generally end up interviewing between 5 and 8 candidates. which is doable for us, but may leave out the 9th candidate even if there was only 0,5 point of difference.

I acknowledge that recruiting will always be arbitrary to some extent, so I'm looking at how maths/stats can help ground my decision instead of making it for me.

I am also open to suggestions that would change other steps such as the weighting or the scoring in order to create clearer breaks among applicants.